# Impala and Hive significant difference in result while calculating correlation coefficient with the help of SD and AVG

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, impala

I have a Hadoop Setup with 8 node Cluster with CDH 5.9.

**Hive Version** :- Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.9.0
*Compiled by jenkins on Fri Oct 21 00:54:46 PDT 2016
From source with checksum 9c5d0bee25fab27d28098c3080f8aedc*

**Impala Version** :- 
Impala v2.7.0-cdh5.9.0 (4b4cf19) built on Fri Oct 21 01:07:22 PDT 2016

**Issue**:-
I ran same query on Hive and Impala (through Hue, Screenshot attached)

```
SELECT (AVG(cost_of_liquidity_provision*risk_of_liquidity_provision)- AVG(cost_of_liquidity_provision)*AVG(risk_of_liquidity_provision))/ (1.00000000*STDDEV_POP(cost_of_liquidity_provision)*STDDEV_POP(risk_of_liquidity_provision)) AS corr_coeff
FROM liquidity
```

The table is in parquet format (non partitioned)

Screenshot
[image: Screenshot of Hive and Impala Notebook]

I got different output in two different runs 
**Hive** :- 0.8465 (correct as verified by external application e.g. R)
**Impala** :- 0.0636

Similar thing happened with another query too.
Accordingly I raised [IMPALA-4841](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-4841) and created [this](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Interactive-Short-cycle-SQL/Impala-and-Hive-significant-difference-in-result-while/m-p/50139#U50139) discussion thread in Cloudera Community.

Any help why this is happening will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do not mention the datatypes of your Parquet columns -- double? integer?

Comment: It's double .. I'll put the table structure

Comment: added more details in https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/IMPALA-4841